# Corona sdk app runs great on emulator, but not when uploaded to Droid

Tags: android, sdk, coronasdk, transition

I have been working a platforming game for about three months. I had the game working fine, and it worked fine on the Droid when uploaded. Recently, I worked on using director.class and a display group and navigating from the menu to the game using director:changeScene(). This works fine on the emulator with no error messages, but when uploaded to the Droid, the main menu loads just fine, but when I touch a button to load the lua file for the game, the screen goes black and nothing happens. I even un-installed several apps in case it was a memory problem, but that didn't change anything. Any help in what I am missing would be appreciated.

Comment: look if you're not breaking any of the specific Android limitations : http://developer.anscamobile.com/reference/troubleshooting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After much searching, I found the answer to my problem: The Corona emulator isn't case sensitive, but the Droid is case sensitive. I found that most of my .png files had uppercase extensions. As an example, pillar.png was actually pillar.PNG in the folder.  Apparently, my graphic editor stores the file extension in uppercase by default. When viewing it with Windows Explorer, it wasn't obvious. I viewed them from the command prompt window and found the problem. Also any requires must be exactly the case as the filenames.  After making this simple change, the apk deployed on the droid just fine. Also in my searching the forums,  I found some other tips. The latest builds of Corona sdk have a problem with files stored in sub directories. Keep all your files in the same directory if you expect to deploy to a Droid.

Jerry

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem and thanks to @Jerry for pointing out images.

In my case image i included had resolution more than 2048 * 2048 (Maximum resolution allowed by Android as of now)

And reducing the image resolution solved the issue for me.

Kudos!!!